# Finding and replacing values of a tag in XML with c sharp

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

```
<TestCase Name="DEBUG">

<ActionEnvironment Name="Carved records indication">
    <Define Name="_TestedVersionPath"         Value="{CustomParam {paramName=PA tested version installer folder path}, {appName=PA installer}, {hint=\\ptnas1\builds\Temp Builds\Forensic\Physical Analyzer\PA.Test\UFED_Analyzer_17.02.05_03-00_6.0.0.128\EncryptedSetup}}"/>
    <Define Name="_PathOfdata"                Value="SharedData\myfolder\mydata.xml"/>
    <ActionSet Name="DEBUG">    
        <Actions>                                                   
            <SpecialAction ActionName="myactionname">
                <CaseName>123</CaseName>
                <UaeSendQueryValues>
                    <URL>192.168.75.133</URL>
                    <RestURL></RestURL>
                    <UserName>user1</UserName>
                    <Password>aaa</Password>
                    <PathOfQuery>_PathOfdata</PathOfQuery>
                    <Method>GET</Method>
                    <ParamsFromFile></ParamsFromFile>
                </UaeSendQueryValues>                                       
            </SpecialAction>
        </Actions>          
    </ActionSet>    
</ActionEnvironment>
```

I have the above xml. i need to find every PathOfQuery tag, get the text of it (in the example _PathOfdata) and then go up in the xml tree and find the first Define tag who's name = to text of PathofQuery tag and get its value (in the example "SharedData\myfolder\mydata.xml")

then i would like to replace that value with another string.

i need to do this for each PathofQuery tag that appears in the xml (it could be more then one) and i want to find always the first apparition of the Define tag (could be more than one) when i travel the tree up from the point where the PathofQuery tag was found.

I want to do this on C Sharp

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: SO questions should show at least minium effort in solving problem and code listing which would reproduce problem which cannot be solved by programmer. Your question seems to be asking for work to be done by SO users in it's entirety without any input from user.

Comment: should i use LINQ to XML for this task?

Comment: how do i travel the tree up from the point i found the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume `string s` holds the above Xml. Then the following code will work for you:

```
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.LoadXml(s);

    XmlNode pathOfQuery = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//PathOfQuery");
    string pathOfQueryValue = pathOfQuery.InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine(pathOfQueryValue);
    XmlNode define = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Define[@Name='" + pathOfQueryValue + "']");
    if(define!=null)
    {
        string defineTagValue = define.Attributes["Value"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(defineTagValue);

        pathOfQuery.InnerText = defineTagValue;

        Console.WriteLine(pathOfQuery.InnerText);
    }
```